# Operand Never Null Warning

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

I'm writing some logic which will get a start date on an object if it isn't null or it will get the min value.

```
var statusStartDate = ((DateTime?)previousCategory?.StartDate) ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Resharper is generating a warning that the Operand is never null:

[image]

If the previous category in the scenario is null, how would this not create a left hand operand being null or is this just a bug in resharper?

**EDIT**

Verifyable Example with DateTime

```
    public class Test
    {
        public Date2 startDate;

        public List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();

        public struct Date2
        {
            public static explicit operator Date2(DateTime date)
            {
                return default(Date2);
            }

            public static explicit operator DateTime(Date2 date)
            {
                return default(DateTime);
            }
        }


        public DateTime BS()
        {
            var tmp = testList.LastOrDefault();
            var testDate = ((DateTime?)tmp?.startDate) ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
            return testDate;
        }
    }

var test = new Test();
test.BS();
var x = test.BS();
```

Comment: Well `previousCategory?.StartDate` will never give you a null value, it will give you `default(DateTime)` which is `01/01/0001 00:00:00`

Comment: @DavidG, previous category is a class and not a struct so that it is possible to have a null value

Comment: Strange, my resharper tells me that your cast to `DateTime` is redundant.

Comment: @RenéVogt StartDate isn't a Datetime, its a custom class just date which is explicitly convertable to DateTime? and DateTime

Comment: @DavidG `previousCategory?.StartDate` is an expression of type `DateTime?`. So it _can_ be null (in the meaning of a `default(Nullable<DateTime>)`)

Comment: @RenéVogt But it's always going to be an actual date that is cast to a nullable date, so Resharper is just saying it will never be null.

Comment: @David how will it always be a date when it ?. returns null if the parent object is null, ?. takes care of casting an object to its nullable form

Comment: @DavidG do you know the null propagation operator `? `? if `previousCategory` is null, it returns a `Nullable<DateTime>` with no value. Syntax sugar let's you treat that as null. The null-coalescing operator `??` would then return the right side. ReSharper is wrong here if it can't prove `previousCategory` may never be null.

Comment: @RenéVogt My assumption was that `StartDate` was a `DateTime`

Comment: @DavidG the type doesn't matter see my edits for another verifyable example with datetime

Comment: @johnny5 Yes, but change `DateTime.MinValue` to `DateTime.MaxValue` and you will see it gives the same date which is `default(DateTime)`

Comment: isn't that obvious? `var tmp = new Test();` how can this become null? if that's your actual code then problem solved! (otherwise post [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example)

Comment: @DavidG that was my fault I forgot to assign the tmp value to null first

Comment: nope. since what you are talking about heavily depends on what code written you should write something that reproduces exact behavior by resharper. your current example does not produce that. and we cant see your actual code. so we cant say why resharper is suggesting that. but don't worry. resharper has become way smarter than you think. just trust it ;) (and always get the latest version ofc)

Comment: @johnny5 I concur with your findings: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i5r1hS

I think resharper is wrong.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Check my new edit this should prove that it is wrong

Comment: Resharper is neglecting the fact that just because there is only a explicit conversion to Datetime the compiler is smart enough to translate that to be applicable to nullable conversions as well

Comment: now we are talking! interesting. you should report it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your test Object:

```
public class Test
{
    public DateTime startDate;
}

void main()
{
 var t = new test();
var time=t.startDate
}
```

time varible  is not null and has "{1/1/0001 12:00:00 }" value
it's the reason that resharper  make a warning.
In some situation for exmaple FirstOrDefault(x=>x...) on a list,  that may have null result, you can user youe code Without any warning

[image]

Update:In second senario Resharper makes mistake because:

```
var check = ((DateTime?) tmp?.startDate).HasValue;// false , startDate is null
```

Comment: this does not reflect the original problem see the new updated example

Comment: your first case will never be null because the assignment is in the line before,   the second case there is no casting

Comment: in second senario:             var check = ((DateTime?) tmp?.startDate).HasValue;// false . so reshrper makes mistake...